# OSX 10.9.2 for the second time

Tags: macos, software-update

I got OSX 10.9.2 update installed on February 26th. Today (March 5th), without prompting, I got another update. The description of the update in App Store is identical. Any idea what  this update was?

[image]

Comment: Just verifying there was a 10.9.1 and then it came the  10.9.2 and then it should show the last 30 days updates?

Comment: I have just added the screenshot.

Comment: You do have it TWICE, that is a new one for me, but thanks for posting the screenshot. Did you purposely mess around with the App Store settings on your computer, so it forgot that it had that installed already?

Comment: I did not. I have got 15" Early 2011 Core i7. Wonder what this update was for. Apples is obscure as always. By the way, in About This Mac Software reads OSX 10.9.2 (13C64)

Comment: For what it is worth: I have the same build and did not get a duplicate update (yet) Retina MBP 15" Early 2013

Comment: 13C64 is what I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you downloaded multiple apps after the 10.9.2

One of those might have done something to the App Store log saved on your computer.

So when checking it id not find and did the 10.9.2 again.

Check this and see if it [fixes the problem](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57530446-263/fix-corrupt-mac-app-store-downloads/).

Comment: I hope it isn't a virus or malware...

Comment: Not a virus at all!